# Ce marking design rules

Tags: design, ce

Does anyone here know anything about ce marking? If I want to design a new electronic product and sell to europe I have to include the ce marking in the pcb. I have found many informations about the design rules for the EMC derictive, but i didn't find much about the Low Voltage Derictive and the Machinery Derictive. I'd like to find some guidelines for the design for these two Derictives.

Comment: People spend entire careers in CE; all the relevant information is at https://www.cenelec.eu/ but beware - it is a hard slog getting through all of it.

Comment: Dave from the EEVBlog made an excellent video about the CE marking and what it means to you as a product designer, watch it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0uvS80YIGU&t=3s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a **Declaration of Conformity** when importing, and the product must have the CE logo.

With it you declare your design is safe an follows the required regulations.
Eg: does not contain banned materials, is not a fire hazard, safe for humans or has warning signs, does not disturb the operation of other devices with unwanted emitted or conducted interference, does not become unsafe when disturbed by interference.

So many guidelines and regulations that only the very large companies can afford to check and test them all. But you can ask experts for an opinion, or ask a test site to perform EMI emission and immunity tests. Which are the most important.
After all, you don't want to disturb cellular, gps or walkie-talkies.

There is no governing body apart from customs who *should* prevent importing of non-CE goods. However, if your product caused problems or harm you might be investigated, and possibly taken to court by a public prosecutor.

Comment: *Anyone* can ask to see the testing performed that was used to claim CE conformity; failure to provide it can land a company in very hot water.

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes, ask. A civilian or company should then prove it's non-conform to actually make the water hot.